# Not displaying the controller in the URL

Tags: codeigniter

How can you hide the controller in the URL?  When a non-registered user comes to my website, I would like them to see:

http://www.site.com/

Once they log-in, then they would be directed to the "Home" controller, then appearing as normal (i.e. http://www.site.com/home)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the 'Home' controller as default, by using CodeIgniter's routing feature.

To set a default controller, open 'application/config/routes.php', and set:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
```

[CodeIgniter - Setting a default controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#default)

[CodeIgniter - URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)